# AngularAMD routes not working

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am using AngularJS alongside RequireJS, but I can't get my app to work properly. When I look in the AngularJS dev tools, it shows the following messages:

`Module "ngRoute" was created but never loaded.
 Module "Welfordian" was created but never loaded.`

Here are my scripts

`Main.JS`

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "assets/js",
paths: {
    'angular': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min',
    'angularAMD': 'angularAMD',
    'ngload': 'ngload',
    'ngRoute': 'angular-route'
},
shim: {
    'angularAMD': ['angular'],
    'ngload': ['angularAMD']
},    
deps: ['app']
});
```

`App.JS`

```
define(['angularAMD', 'ngRoute'], function (angularAMD, ngRoute) {
var app = angular.module('Welfordian', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when(
        "/home",
        angularAMD.route({
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerUrl: 'controllers'
        })
    ).otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
});

return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```

Comment: Did you check that the .js files for required libraries and app got loaded?

Comment: It looks as thought everything has been loaded fine. angular.module("welfordian") returns what I expect.

Comment: So what exactly is not functioning? I assume the messages you see could be informational.

Comment: Okay, I'm now getting `[$injector:unpr]`. I think it could have something to do with ngRoute, but it looks like I'm loading it correctly, no?

Comment: First of all, when developing, do not use the minified angularjs. Include the plain version and the error messages will become much more informative.
Now it is hard to tell what exactly went wrong.